Recovering function from moving average $\bar{f}(a,x)=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^a dy\,f(x+y)$
The moving average of a function $f(x)$ is defined as
$$\bar{f}(a,x)\equiv\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^a \mathrm{d}y\,f(x+y).$$
Is there a way to recover the original function from the moving average, i.e. from $\bar{f}(a,x)$ back to $f(x)$? I imagine there are cases where this is simply not possible, but maybe there is a general formula for a certain class of functions.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated :)

Explore the Fourier transform.

@Aruralreader You're right! That's so obvious (facepalm). But that leaves the question if there is a way to solve the resulting inverse Fourier transform in general, but that's another question. Thanks!

This is only unique among band-limited functions since you can add any $2a$-periodic function with mean zero and obtain the same moving average

To underline the point made by @whpowell96: is the intention that $\bar{f}(a,x)$ is known for all $x$ and some fixed $a$, or for arbitrary $a>0$ as well? If we allow the latter, then $\bar{f}(a,x)\to f(x)$ as $a \to 0^+$. So knowing the moving average with arbitrary width is sufficient to recover the original function, but knowing just one such moving average is not.

Good points! One only knows the moving average of a single width. I already guessed it wouldn't be unique, but you probably could do some "principal value" type of thing with the result, so result modulo periodic function :)
